# How does MSMQ manage messages?

Tags: queue, msmq

It seems that MSMQ doesn't use any Database management system to manage messages.
How does MSMQ manage messages?
Does it store the messages in flat file?

I'm trying to implement a messages management system.

Comment: There are many more file organizations than "DBMS" and "flat" believe me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSMQ uses flat files located in %windir%\system32\msmq.

If you want to implement your own queueing, I suggest you take a look at [Ayende's blog post on queueing](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/01/Rhino-Queues.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

it stores them as files on the disk.

If you wanna manage them use the System.Messaging API